# How to slow down translation speed in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am using Sprite `translate(xAmount, yAmount)` method to move object by given offset. Is there a way to slow down this translation so that I can create smooth animation of moving objects. I could delay drawing in frames but that doesn't sound good approach.

eg. Code.

```
                    model.getSprite().translate(x, y);
```

Draw Code

```
                   model.getSprite().draw(game.batch);
```

Comment: You didn't provide enough information. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Don't make people guess what you are doing, instead provide the http://sscce.org.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to draw it frame by frame, translating it a little bit at a time.

Answer (score -1):

`

```
float sx=0.5f; // slow down translation factor in x axis by half 

float sy=0.5f; // slow down translation factor in y axis by half

model.getSprite().translate(x*sx, y*sy);
```

`
For example:
if you want translation slow down only along x axis then set value of sy = 1 and value of sx from 0 to 1 where 0 results in no movement while .5 in half speed slow down.
If you want no change in translation speed set sx or sy value 1 , setting its value more than that will increase its speed.

Comment: That won't slow anything down, just move it to the wrong place.

Comment: It would decrease the translation steps hence slow down the translation

Comment: @atuos If you understand the answer then kindly just don't vote down a answer as something going off your head might be useful for someone else

Comment: abhimanyud3dx I understand your answer, I just think it is quite poor. Your code, as presented, will just move it half the distance it needs to go. Even if we assume the missing control code which ensures that it gets translated all the way to the destination over consecutive renderings, the animation speed will depend on the hardware.

Comment: The libgdx runs at fixed fps untill vsync is turned off, assuming the control code has a coordinate say move till model.getX()<=100; the translationx*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*sx; will make it move irrespective of hardware on the basis of time, i hope you have worked on libgdx.

Comment: Yes, deltatime is what your answer is missing. Also, dependence on vsync being turned off is a strange limitation. Not to mention hardware which runs it at a lower FPS than the vsync limit.

Comment: That delta time was supposed to be precalculated on x or on y in translate(x,y);

Comment: Oh, I see. I understand the question differently. I understand that he moves the sprite in one step with one call to translate.